# Windows reverse engineering: find a specific Windows structure

Tags: c, windows, assembly, reverse-engineering, windbg

I'm doing some reverse on Windows (x64) kernel with Windbg. 
I try to determine the structure represented by the following bytes:

**0e 00 10 00 00 00 00 00** - **90 db fe db 12 00 00 00**

I assume that:

- **90 db fe db 12 00 00 00** is a pointer to a string

> kd> d 12dbfedb90
>
> *00000012`dcec7210*  63 00 6f 00 75 00 6e - 00 74 00 72 00 79 00 00 c.o.u.n.t.r.y.

- **0e 00** is the size of the string
- **10 00** is the size of the string with the terminating null byte

So I think the original structure looks like the following:

```
typedef struct _SSTR {
    WORD   wStringLen;
    WORD   wStringWithNullCharLen; // Must be wStringLen + 1
    DWORD  dwReserved; // Must be 0
    PWSTR  pwString;
} SSTR;
typedef SSTR *PSSTR;
```

This structure may be documented in the MSDN but I didn't found anything... What is the Windows structure that corresponds to these bytes ?

Comment: Why not look at the APIs that access it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like

```
typedef struct _STRING {
  USHORT Length;
  USHORT MaximumLength;
  PCHAR  Buffer;
} STRING, OEM_STRING, *PSTRING;
```

from [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648424(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

In which your `dwReserved` is padding for the `PCHAR  Buffer` pointer.

Or could be [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff564879(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff564879%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
which is quite similar

```
typedef struct _UNICODE_STRING {
  USHORT Length;
  USHORT MaximumLength;
  PWSTR  Buffer;
} UNICODE_STRING, *PUNICODE_STRING;
```

Comment: Dxxn fast! Do you know the win32 structures by heard? S-)

Comment: It's a UNICODE_STRING, note that the string it points to is a wide character string. You can dump a UNICODE_STRING structure in WinDbg with dS